# AntD Tree: need help! can't pass react element as icon OR title for antd tree

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using the AntD tree and I have a react element that I want to pass as either an icon or a title because it has custom styling. Due to it being IP I can't share too much code, but my question is:
how can I pass a react element (see below i.e. generic name) as either a title or icon and have antD tree render it?

i.e. this is what I want to pass as a prop to the icon or title

```js
import React from 'react';

const genericName = (props) => {
  // code uses props to get some infor for Color
  // cant share code due to proprietary reasons
  // but it is not needed for this question
  
    const colorHTML = getColor(Color);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={`colors from`}>${colorHTML}</div>
            {pin}
        </div>
    );
};

export default genericName;
```

in my console you can see node.icon is a typeof react.element. I want to target that and just pass the prop into antD tree as either title or icon

[image: Json displaying info of icon]

i.e.

```html
return (
  <Tree
    icon={node.icon}
    />
  )
```

I've searched and similar answers were given before antD forbid the use of children and strictly allows treeData. All examples I see only use strings in titles/icons, but since antD documentation is very limited, I need to know if my use case is possible. Right now, for the life of me I can't understand why it doesn't populate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely work to put a JSX component as `title` within `treeData`. Take a look at this snippet, I added a Icon here in one of the titles:

```
import React from 'react'


import  { RightCircleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'

type Props = {}

import { Tree } from 'antd';
import type { DataNode, TreeProps } from 'antd/es/tree';

const treeData: DataNode[] = [
  {
    title: <span>{<RightCircleOutlined />} parent</span>, //icon added here
    key: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'parent 1-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        disabled: true,
        children: [
          {
            title: 'leaf',
            key: '0-0-0-0',
            disableCheckbox: true,
          },
          {
            title: 'leaf',
            key: '0-0-0-1',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'parent 1-1',
        key: '0-0-1',
        children: [{ title: <span style={{ color: '#1890ff' }}>sss</span>, key: '0-0-1-0' }],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const Demo: React.FC = () => {
  const onSelect: TreeProps['onSelect'] = (selectedKeys, info) => {
    console.log('selected', selectedKeys, info);
  };

  const onCheck: TreeProps['onCheck'] = (checkedKeys, info) => {
    console.log('onCheck', checkedKeys, info);
  };

  return (
    <Tree
      checkable
      defaultExpandedKeys={['0-0-0', '0-0-1']}
      defaultSelectedKeys={['0-0-0', '0-0-1']}
      defaultCheckedKeys={['0-0-0', '0-0-1']}
      onSelect={onSelect}
      onCheck={onCheck}
      treeData={treeData}
    />
  );
};

export default Demo;
```