# How to apply a css class on antd tree node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antD Tree component. I have a tree structure where node can be of type directory or file. I want to display the names of directory in bold. Is there a way to specify class for Tree items via json definition?

Comment: take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74414251/2127432
You can specify the title of the tree-object as a react component

Comment: Thanks a lot! that solved my problem. If you want you can log an answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the title as a react component within the JSON-config of the tree:

```
const treeData: DataNode[] = [
  {
    title: <span>{<RightCircleOutlined />} parent</span>, //icon added here
    key: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'parent 1-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        disabled: true,
        children: [
          {
            title: 'leaf',
            key: '0-0-0-0',
            disableCheckbox: true,
          },
          {
            title: 'leaf',
            key: '0-0-0-1',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'parent 1-1',
        key: '0-0-1',
        children: [{ title: <span style={{ color: '#1890ff' }}>sss</span>, key: '0-0-1-0' }],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This example is from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74414251/2127432):